# Firefox not including cookies when using netConnection (RTMPT)

Tags: firefox, cookies, rtmp, httponly, netconnection

I am trying (for days) to make this work: I want to connect to a Media Servers using RTMPT netConnection. In order to reach that, I have to pass an authentication cookie along with my request. In Chrome and IE it works, but in Firefox it doesen't pass the auth_cookie.

When I look into logs I see the /open/1 request, but it has no cookie atached. Againg: in Chrome and IE it uses the cookie. The cookie doesn't have the HttpOnly flag.

Another weird scenario that I encountered is: Because it dosen't pass the cookie, the ApplicationServer wich holds the autentication, asks me for credentials. If I enter them it takes the cookie and works, and any subsequent connections work (firefox passes the auth_cookie along the /open/1 request); but if I delete all the cookies in browser (via CookieController-> Remove ALL cookies and DOM storage) the credentials are requested again (no cookie is passed).

Any sugestions? I've searched all the internet for a solution but I can't find anything...